# Is there a way to stop plotting values after certain x value?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I'm using matplotlib for plotting results from training a Neural Network.

I successfully managed to plot my result using `make_interp_spline` on a given x-axis of 50 (Epochs).¹

Of course, x and y have the same size (both have 9 values), so it was easy for me to plot them. Now, I have to show multiple results on the same plot and so I need a different value on the x-axis, because certain results are based on a value (Epoch - which is my x-axis) > 50 (such as 60,70, etc..).

I tried to initialize a linspace > 50 and it works, but the results are going up in an exponential way.²
Is there a way to "delete" points starting from x = 50?

Plus, if I add values in the x-axis, python throws me an error saying:

```
ValueError: Shapes of x (14,) and y (10,) are incompatible
```

I'm going to leave what I achieved until now.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

listA = [0.00,25.98386517667222,36.10066770794748,
         31.70895801412648,29.430944916297648,
         27.164039966977874,30.26995937742036,
         29.23696275469900,28.11570993620774,
         28.608378364299906]

epochList = [0, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]

xnew = np.linspace(0, 50, 100)  
spl_A = make_interp_spline(epochList, listA, k=3)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))

plt.plot(xnew, spl_A(xnew), label='A')
plt.scatter(epochList,listA)

plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(epochList), max(epochList)+1, 5.0))

plt.ylabel('MAE')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 62, 5.0))

del listA[0]
plt.scatter(epochList[listA.index(min(listA))+1], min(listA), label=F'Best MAE = {min(listA)}', s=200, marker='*', c='black')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size': 14})

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: ¹] [image: ²]

Comment: What is your code for the second graph?

Comment: Simply edit `xnew = np.linspace(0, **50**, 100)` to  `xnew = np.linspace(0, **70**, 100)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be changing `listA`. From the second graph, it looks like it's plotting the old `interolop` function with new `xnew`. Since the old graph is exponential at the end, the new graph's end part becomes exponential. I am assuming you have new 'MAE' data for the later 'epoch'. So, you have to put those data in `listA`. The error you showed likely occurred from you adding new values to `epoch` list but not adding anything to `listA`.

Comment: I get what you're saying :) But, the problem is: Imagine that, besides plotting `listA`, I have a `listB` to plot with 10 values, not 9 (as you said). The `epochList` would be initialized to 10 values in this case, but then Python would throw an error while plotting `listA` because the list is composed of 9 values, while the `epochList` has 10. I hope you got me. :)

Comment: I still do not understand why would you want to initialize with two different sizes? If you have two lists for y-data then you can just concatenate them. If you can give more detail about your data, maybe I can help.

Comment: Sure thing. If I give detail about data, it would be too much complicated. So, think about the program as I wrote it in the OP. What I want to achieve is this: https://i.imgur.com/lwXuJuH.png . The green line goes until epoch 55. The orange and blue stop at 50. The problem is that the orange and the blue have 9 values to plot, while the green has 10, hence the error Python gives me, because orange and blue have 9 y-values to plot on a 10 x-values. Please note that all the 3 lists are being plotted using the same `epochList` (10 values). I hope this wasn't too much confusing. :)

Comment: The solution is to either pad the shorter lists with `None` or make separate `epoch` lists. e.g., `epoch1 = [5,10,...,50]`, `epoch2 = [5,10,...,70]`.

Comment: Creating 2 lists, 2 linspaces and plotting the larger list on that specific linspace (70), resolved my issue! This is what I got: https://i.imgur.com/oX8vkAe.png

Thanks a lot man, sorry for the misunderstanding! :)